# How to add a custom tag to spacy NER

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I would like to add some tags to `"en_core_web_sm"`
For example: I want the Spacy NER model to tag "16GB" as a RAM and "Intel core i7" as a CPU
How can I do this?

I tried the following:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") 
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
patterns = [{"label": "RAM", "pattern": "16gb ram"}]


ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler")
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
doc = nlp("16gb ram is my order")
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text,ent.label_)
```

and the output was: 16 CARDINAL

Comment: Can you explain the output "16 CARDINAL"? I think 16 is the text and CARDINAL is the label. But how did you get the label?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add new tags with the EntityRuler you can do that by setting `overwrite_ents = True`. See [here](https://spacy.io/api/entityruler/#config) in the docs, but it looks something like this:

```
config = {"overwrite_ents": True}
nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler", config=config)
```